# Removing item from XML file

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, removeall

I have the following XML structure:

```
<Catalog>
  <sensors>
    <Item>
      <Item_Number>Mblah123</Item_Number>
      <Category>Vibration</Category>
      <Language>English</Language>
      <Description>desc</Description>
      <Long_Description><![CDATA[wow!]]></Long_Description>
      <BOM><![CDATA[]]></BOM>
      <Recommended_Parts></Recommended_Parts>
      <Picture>pic.jpg</Picture>
    </Item>
  </sensors>
  <technology>
    <Item>
      <Item_Number>test003</Item_Number>
      <Category>Vibration</Category>
      <Language>Japanese</Language>
      <Description>description</Description>
      <Long_Description><![CDATA[rsxgrdxgtxtxg]]></Long_Description>
      <BOM>
        <![CDATA[xwthgwtg
    trxthtrh
    trxeyrxjyetj
    txrhueyjh]]>
      </BOM>
      <Recommended_Parts>xtrwth</Recommended_Parts>
      <Picture>pic.jpg</Picture>
    </Item>
  </technology>
</Catalog>
```

In my .NET page, I have this code behind that's used for removing specific items:

```
Private Sub DeleteData(ByVal fileName As String, ByVal strSelection As String)
    lblData.Text = ""
    Dim strContent As String = ""

    Dim m_xmld As XmlDocument
    'Dim m_nodelist As XmlNodeList
    Dim m_node As XmlNode
    'Create the XML Document
    m_xmld = New XmlDocument()
    'Load the Xml file
    m_xmld.Load(fileName)

    m_node = m_xmld.SelectSingleNode(strSelection)

    m_node.RemoveAll()

    m_xmld.Save(fileName)

    MsgBox("Entry removed!")
End Sub
```

But when I use it on, say the technology item, it retains the  node:

```
<Catalog>
  <sensors>
    <Item>
      <Item_Number>Mblah123</Item_Number>
      <Category>Vibration</Category>
      <Language>English</Language>
      <Description>desc</Description>
      <Long_Description><![CDATA[wow!]]></Long_Description>
      <BOM><![CDATA[]]></BOM>
      <Recommended_Parts></Recommended_Parts>
      <Picture>pic.jpg</Picture>
    </Item>
  </sensors>
  <technology>
    <Item>
    </Item>
  </technology>
</Catalog>
```

How do I specify that even the Item tags need to be removed?

TIA!

**Addendum**

I call the sub via:

DeleteData(MapPath("Catalog1.xml"), "/Catalog/" + ddlL1Cat.SelectedValue.ToString + "/Item[Item_Number='" + ddlItemNum.SelectedValue + "']")

strSelection would have this kind of value:  **"/Catalog/technology/Item[Item_Number='test003']"**

Comment: You need to give us the value for `strSelection` so that we can test what's going wrong in order to give an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity   I've edited the query :) The value of strSelection goes something like this: **"/Catalog/" + ddlL1Cat.SelectedValue.ToString + "/Item[Item_Number='" + ddlItemNum.SelectedValue + "']"** in value, it should look like this: **"/Catalog/technology/Item[Item_Number='test003']"**